# Relational database schema - Relationship and Foreign keys

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, schema, relational-database

I am having a hard time understanding when to have a relationship between entities in the following case:

If I have some entities which have a foreign key, say a field named node_id, which represents the id of a note, and a Notes entity, is it necessary to have a relationship between those entities?

Here is a subset of my schema which might be more explicit
[image: Schema]

Comment: You seem have some confusions about entities, relationships, associations, tables, ids and FKs that I address in my answer but that do not seem to be clarified in the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a field as foreign key you are already setting a relationship between the two tables in your database, so i assume your question is only about the schema representation.

The answer is yes. If you have a foreign key from table A to table B it means that rows in table A have a connection with table B and in your schema you need to specify and visualize this connection.

Schemas are useful because they give a fast and precise explanation of your database structure, if you omit relations, someone reading your scheme may not understand why there are some fields or may not find the best way to create a query that requires that relation.

A wrong schema or an incomplete schema is really useless

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about entities, relationships, diagrams, tables and FKs.

In this style of ER diagram (the original), boxes are for entitiy types and diamonds are for relationship/association types. (The "R" in ER means "relationship" in the sense of association.) Each type gets a table. The lines from a diamond to a box represent participation of referenced entities in the association. They correspond to FKs from the association table referencing the entity table.

Beware: Depending on the information modeling method or presentation of it, "relationship" sometimes means "association", sometimes means "foreign key" and sometimes means a line that would have an association diamond in the middle of it in this diagram style.

(Some diagramming methods allow "associative entities". An associative entity is one formed from a list of participants in some association. Such an entity can participate in further associations. That corresponds to a composite FK composed from the entity ids from the further association's table to the original's. This means that not only must entities that form the associative entity participate in the further association but they also have to participate in the original association. Without associative entities a diagram can't express that. When you diagram participation of an association entity in a further association you don't need to also explicitly express the direct participation of its constituent entities in the further association. Nor the corresponding direct FKs.)

Answer (score 1):

In the entity-relationship model, foreign key constraints enforce the type of an entity set in a relationship.  Thus, if you have an FK, that means there's a relationship too.  Don't confuse the two, though - an FK is a binary subset relation which enforces one entity set, a relationship is an n-ary relation that can involve multiple different entity sets (and multiple FK constraints).

Your example describes explicit relationships with Notes which should be indicated in your diagram.